# Is there a REQUEST_URI in Flask?

Tags: php, flask

Using the request object in Flask, is there a REQUEST_URI (like in PHP) ?

`'REQUEST_URI':
The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Flask you can get it from the `request` object as `request.path`. See [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path) for more details, including other attributes of the request object that are related and may also be useful.